# что использовать для сеточной верстки bootstrap или fast-grid или свою

Tags: css3, html5

что вы используйте для этого в 2020 году

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @dim0n тут могут быть и ответы на фактах и на мыслях я сам из этого разберу что нужно уже смотря на процент ответов большинства

Comment: Такие вопросы оффтопик на сайте, при желании можно задать их в чате

Comment: @dim0n а как это?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @dim0n спасибо.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на bootstrap   -- https://getbootstrap.com/